# Getting 'npm start' error when trying to build React Native app on iphone?

Tags: ios, node.js, react-native

When I do a build to my iphone 6 I get the following error on my device with the red screen:

```
"Could not connect to development server. Ensure node server is running - run 'npm start' from React root

The operation couldn't be completed.
(NSURLErrorDomain error - 1004)"
```

And im getting the following error in terminal in the React Packager:

```
"Unhandled rejection Error: ENOENT, open '/Users/rahulsharma/Desktop/rcapp/.git/index.lock'"
```

Lastly, I am getting this in the xcode console:

```
2015-05-06 12:37:48.631 rcapp[808:262187] CLTilesManagerClient: XPC_ERROR_CONNECTION_INVALID!
```

Any ideas?

here is the code in git:

https://github.com/rahul1346/rcapp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at AppDelegate.m and update accordingly.

```
// To run on device, change `localhost` to the IP address of your computer, and make sure your computer and
// iOS device are on the same Wi-Fi network.
jsCodeLocation = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle"];
```